# Drag and Drop Image Anywhere

Tags: javascript

I found a post from awhile back that was very useful for something I'm working on. I need the functionality of dragging and dropping an object (an image in my case) wherever I want, and then dropping it wherever I want without changing the content around it.

However, I can't seem to get it to work with a simple image rather than a code block. I'm sure it's an easy fix and I'm just overlooking something, but I'd appreciate the help.

This example is perfect from the aforementioned SO post: http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/kKuqH/
(this is with a code block, but I want an image instead)

```
function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
} 
function drag_over(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
} 
function drop(event) { 
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
var dm = document.getElementById('dragme'); 
dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the image the background image of the div. Change your CSS to something like this:

```
aside { 
    position:  absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: This is the moment where I facepalm because this solution is so simple. This will work for me! Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, we've all been there!